# grouper with unstack ()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe,df

```
       date     name   count
 0  2017-08-07  ABC      12
 1  2017-09-08  ABC      5
 2  2017-09-22  TTT      6
 3  2017-09-23  TAC      5
 4  2017-10-09  ABC      10
```

It should now be:

```
   Index      ABC    TTT     TAC 
  August      12      0      0
  September   5       6      5
  October     10      0      0
```

Then sum for each month

```
    index          
   August      12     
   September   16      
   October     10
```

Here is the code:

```
df.date= pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).unstack().sum()# groupby each 1 month
df2.index = df2.index.strftime('%B')
print(df2)
```

I get this error:AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'unstack' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: I think pandas restricts access to `unstack` on purpose because this does (don't ask me why, I don't know enough about pandas) not make sense for a `GroupBy` instance. Can you follow the advice in the error message and use `apply` instead?

Comment: try doing `sum()` before `unstack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unstack is used to remove a level of indices from a multi index. You applied unstack before you used an aggregation function. That's why you got the error. Even then I think there are some issues with your groupby. Does the following work for you?

```
df.date= pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df2 = df.groupby( [pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M'),"name"])["count"].sum().unstack()
df2.index = df2.index.strftime('%B')
print(df2)
```

Comment: I got  this:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: Can you post the code you run? Or at least the line  with to_datetime

Comment: cA.date= cA.to_datetime(cA.date)...sorry,let me correct it

Comment: to_datetime is a function from the library. Should be pd.to_datetime(cA.date)

Comment: it works fine now, thanks but it doesn't add up all the values monthly

Comment: what does it output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161657/discussion-between-gabriel-a-and-bode).